# HA Proxy fails ssl validation

Tags: haproxy

We are using a Godaddy wild card certificate on HA **(Wildcard.pem)** and custom CA certs on the backends. The in-house CA is trusted by HA and all servers. I can access all backend servers individually without any problems but when we enable SSL validation, the health check fails with 503 error almost immediately.

HA configs

```
frontend api.qa.domain.com_esil_HTTPS_443_VS_172.20.25.69
    mode http
    bind 172.20.25.69:80
    bind 172.20.25.69:443 ssl crt /etc/hapee-2.4/ssl/Wildcard.pem ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2
    http-after-response replace-header set-cookie "^(my.session=.*)" "\1; SameSite=Strict" 
    http-request set-var(txn.path) path
    http-request set-var(req.backend) str(api.qa.domain.com_loggingservices_http_33313_POOL) if { path -i -m beg /loggingservice/ }
    
    use_backend %[var(req.backend)]

    backend api.qa.domain.com_loggingservice_http_333_POOL
    mode http
    http-request return status 503 content-type "text/html; charset=utf-8" lf-file /etc/hapee-2.4/apps/app_offline.htm if { nbsrv() le 0 }

    balance roundrobin
    dynamic-cookie-key Av3ryS3curek3y
    option httpchk GET /loggingservice/v1/_healthcheck HTTP/1.1
    http-check send hdr host api.qa.domain.com
    http-check expect status 200
    server QA_SERVER1_Node 10.133.20.24:333 check ssl verify none
```

Do I need to merge our backend certs which we created using our CA with the GoDaddy pem file? if yes, what would be the correct order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to merge the custom CA certs with the GoDaddy cert file to create a combined cert file that can be used as the value for the ca-file option in your HAProxy backend server configuration. The correct order for the certificates in the combined file is:

The leaf certificate (your GoDaddy wildcard cert)

The intermediate certificate (GoDaddy's cert chain)

The root certificate (your custom CA cert)

To create the combined cert file, you can use a text editor to copy and paste the contents of each certificate file into a single file in the correct order. Alternatively, you can use the cat command in Linux to concatenate the files, like this:

```
cat leaf.crt intermediate.crt customCA.crt > combined_cert.pem
```

Once you have created the combined cert file, you can update your HAProxy backend server configuration to use the ssl verify required ca-file option, like this:

```
backend api.qa.domain.com_loggingservice_http_333_POOL
    mode http
    http-request return status 503 content-type "text/html; charset=utf-8" lf-file /etc/hapee-2.4/apps/app_offline.htm if { nbsrv() le 0 }

    balance roundrobin
    dynamic-cookie-key Av3ryS3curek3y
    option httpchk GET /loggingservice/v1/_healthcheck HTTP/1.1
    http-check send hdr host api.qa.domain.com
    http-check expect status 200
    server QA_SERVER1_Node 10.133.20.24:333 check ssl verify required ca-file /path/to/combined_cert.pem
```

With this configuration, HAProxy will verify the SSL certificates presented by the backend servers using the custom CA cert, and the health check should pass if the certificates are valid.